# Convert percentage value to int

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to convert in JavaScript for an example 7.35% to int value, so that I get 7.35 as result?

Note: method parseInt() does not work!

Comment: 7.35 is not an **int**eger - try `parseFloat()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use parseFloat

```
parseFloat('42.42%');// => float val = 42.42
```

Comment: This works, but why this is not working. var x=5%; parseFloat(x);

Comment: @mehmedju: I think you mean `var x = "5%";`.  You can't just have a `%` after a number, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake . `var x=5 + "%" ; parseFloat(x);`

Comment: this code ``var x=5 + "%" ; parseFloat(x);`` work for me

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` does not work because it's not an integer. You can use `parseFloat()` instead.

Example

```js
var x = '7.35%';
document.write(parseFloat(x));
```

---

*Reference*

- [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat() instead of parseInt